# Blazor Re-Ordering A list With Drag And Drop

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am learning Blazor having come from a WinForm UWP background. I have a list of Game:

```
public class Game
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
List<Game> Games = new List<Game> {
new Game() { ID= "Game1", Text= "American Football"},
new Game() { ID= "Game2", Text= "Badminton"  },
new Game() { ID= "Game3", Text= "Basketball"  },
new Game() { ID= "Game4", Text= "Cricket"},
new Game() {  ID= "Game5", Text= "Football" },
new Game() { ID= "Game6", Text= "Golf"  },
new Game() { ID= "Game7", Text= "Hockey"  },
new Game() { ID= "Game8", Text= "Rugby" },
new Game() { ID= "Game9", Text= "Snooker"  },
new Game() { ID= "Game10", Text= "Tennis" },
```

};
I want to drag and drop to reorder my list. Here is my Element.

```
<ul ondragover="event.preventDefault();" style="margin:20px">
@foreach (var item in Games)
{
    <li draggable="true" style="list-style-type:none; height:30px" @key="item" tabindex="1"
        @onclick="@(()=> ClickItem(item))" @ondrop="@(()=> Drop(item))">
        <span>@item.Text</span>
    </li>
}
```

I select an item in the list with the @onclick:

```
Game currentGame;
int currentIndex;
void ClickItem(Game item)
{
    currentIndex = Games.FindIndex(a => a.Text == item.Text);
    currentGame = item;
}
```

And I handle the ondrop with:

```
    void Drop(Game item)
{
    var newIndex = Games.FindIndex(a => a.Text == item.Text);
    Games.Insert(newIndex, currentGame);
    Games.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Nothing happens in the Drop method the list does not change and the app breaks but throws no error and navigation stops.All the events are firing. Can't find any examples of S.O. to help.

Comment: I don't think `onclick` is involved in drag&drop. You start it with `drag()`

Comment: Here is a blog: https://chrissainty.com/investigating-drag-and-drop-with-blazor/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I managed to create a working example in BlazorFiddle for you:

https://blazorfiddle.com/s/8jurefka

As per Henk's suggestion I replaced your `ClickItem` with a `StartDrag` method which handles the `@ondrag` event. If you use `@onclick` you have to click an item first before you can drag it. Using the `@ondrag` event you can avoid this. I think this might have been the cause of the problems in some cases.

I also added a few debugging helpers so I could see what is happening.

Here is the same code as shown in the BlazorFiddle example:

```cs
@page "/"

<h1>DragDrop demo</h1>
<ul ondragover="event.preventDefault();" style="margin:20px">
@foreach (var item in Games)
{
    if(item != null)     //Change @ondrop to @ondragover to update UI in real time 
    {
    <li draggable="true" style="list-style-type:none; height:30px" 
     @key="item.ID" tabindex="1"
     @ondrop="@(()=> Drop(item))" 
     @ondrag="@(()=> StartDrag(item))">
          <span>@item.Text</span> <small>@item.ID</small>
    </li>
    } else 
    {
        <li>NULL??</li>
    }
}
</ul>

<button @onclick="ReportList" >List</button>
@code
{

    int currentIndex;

    void StartDrag(Game item)
    {
        currentIndex = GetIndex(item);
        Console.WriteLine($"DragStart for {item.ID} index {currentIndex}");
    }

    void ClickItem(Game item)
    {
        currentIndex = GetIndex(item);
    }

    int GetIndex(Game item)
    {
        return Games.FindIndex(a => a.ID == item.ID);
    }

    void Drop(Game item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Drop item {item.Text} ({item.ID})");
            var index = GetIndex(item);
            Console.WriteLine($"Drop index is {index}, move from {currentIndex}");
            // get current item
            var current = Games[currentIndex];
            // remove game from current index
            Games.RemoveAt(currentIndex);
            Games.Insert(index, current);

            // update current selection
            currentIndex = index;

            StateHasChanged();
        } 
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Drop - null");
        }
    }

    void ReportList()
    {
        int i =0;
        foreach (var item in Games)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i++}: {item.ID} = {item.Text}");
        }
    }

    public class Game
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Text;
        }
    }

    List<Game> Games = new List<Game> {
    new Game() { ID= "Game1", Text= "American Football"},
    new Game() { ID= "Game2", Text= "Badminton"  },
    new Game() { ID= "Game3", Text= "Basketball"  },
    new Game() { ID= "Game4", Text= "Cricket"},
    new Game() { ID= "Game5", Text= "Football" },
    new Game() { ID= "Game6", Text= "Golf"  },
    new Game() { ID= "Game7", Text= "Hockey"  },
    new Game() { ID= "Game8", Text= "Rugby" },
    new Game() { ID= "Game9", Text= "Snooker"  },
    new Game() { ID= "Game10", Text= "Tennis" },
    };
}
```

Comment: Forget to mention I used the `item.ID` as the `@key` value rather than the whole item

Comment: This answer seems to use JQuery. Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of using Blazor?

Comment: @redoc the example template has JQuery because Bootstrap uses JQuery, but it's not part of the solution and can be removed if you wish

Comment: Yes, I see.  Thank you for the clarification.  Nice solution..

Comment: You are the best. Nice solution. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped, @zAnthony !

Comment: @Quango , instead of using the OnDrop, I use on OnDragOver makes the UI more responsive.  As you're dragging over Objects, the DOM reacts and shift the objects in realtime.  My only question is, can the opacity be change so the object doesn't become transparent?

Comment: @zAnthony I'm not a CSS expert but I think there are CSS event classes that should help you do this, e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondragover.asp

Comment: Works nicely. Thank you!

Comment: Warning ! if you are using server side blazor, ondrag is a performance killer (ut if you really need to be notified for any mouse movement, go for it) . Use a @ondragstart event instead. 
Based on the solution, something like that : 
<div ondragover="event.preventDefault();">
    @ foreach (var item in Data)
    {
        <div style="width: 100%;border:1px solid black" draggable="true" @ ondragstart="@ (()=> StartDrag(item))" @ondrop="@(() =>DropOn(item))">
            @Template?.Invoke(item)
        </div>
    }
</div>

Comment: Great demo (+1). However, when applied to my Blazor wasm app I noticed a huge delay when reordering a large list.   The fix was to change  @ondrag="@(()=> StartDrag(item))" to @ondragstart="@(()=> StartDrag(item))".  It was very quick after this change.

Comment: It does not seem to work on a touch device. Not complaining, just saying.

Answer (score 18):

You can do it in Blazor only - no external js library needed:

[image: drag and drop in blazor]

```
<ul ondragover="event.preventDefault();"
    ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('', event.target.id);">
    @foreach (var item in Models.OrderBy(x => x.Order))
    {
        <li @ondrop="()=>HandleDrop(item)" @key="item">
            <div @ondragleave="@(()=> {item.IsDragOver = false;})"
                @ondragenter="@(()=>{item.IsDragOver = true;})"
                style="@(item.IsDragOver?"border-style: solid none none none; border-color:red;":"")"
                @ondragstart="() => draggingModel = item"
                @ondragend="()=> draggingModel = null" draggable="true">@item.Name</div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>

@code
{
    public List<Model> Models { get; set; } = new();

    public class Model
    {
        public int Order { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";
        public bool IsDragOver{ get; set; } 
    }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {//fill names with "random" string
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Model m = new() { Order = i, Name = $"Item {i}" };
            Models.Add(m);
        }
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void HandleDrop(Model landingModel)
    {//landing model -> where the drop happened
        if (draggingModel is null) return;
        int originalOrderLanding = landingModel.Order;//keep the original order for later
        //increase model under landing one by 1
        Models.Where(x => x.Order >= landingModel.Order).ToList().ForEach(x => x.Order++);
        draggingModel.Order = originalOrderLanding;//replace landing model
        int ii = 0;
        foreach (var model in Models.OrderBy(x=>x.Order).ToList())
        {
            model.Order = ii++;//keep the numbers from 0 to size-1
            model.IsDragOver = false;//remove drag over. 
        }
    }

    private Model? draggingModel;//the model that is being dragged
}
```

The full project is available in my [GitHub repository](https://github.com/tesar-tech/DragAndDropList).

Edit: .NET 8 update just arrived. Also with solution for ordering as the last item.

Comment: Solution works, but if any item is dropped on last item it does not work

Comment: @SurinderSingh Now it does. Check the github repo.

Comment: ondrop is fired more than 1 time here. did you experience same issue?

Comment: @Emil can you open an issue in the repo? That will make sure I don't forget to look into that